# How can I use pyspark.mllib rdd api metric to measure pyspark.ml (new dataframe api)?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

The old API of MlLib has evaluation metric class: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html
However, the new dataframe API does NOT have such a class: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html

It has the Evaluator class but it is limited.

How can I evaluate a model in the new API using the metric class of the old one?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert a DataFrame into a RDD using `.rdd()` (in pyspark)

Hence, you can make the final model using the `pyspark.ml` likbrary, and then find the predictions of the testing data and do `testing_predictions.rdd()` and use that RDD in functions from `pyspark.mllib`.